# WSS Search fills 10 GB limit on SBS server 2011

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, windows-sbs

I've got a SBS Server 2011 Standard SP1 that isn't very busy. 2 Users local and 2 remote. We have sharepoint that has maybe a dozen small documents at most.

I've just started getting the following two error occur

Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.MSSBatchHistory'.'IX_MSSBatchHistory' in database 'WSS_Search_SERVER' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

And

CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.

Digging around in SQL manager I see that WSS Search DB file size is  10241MB, the log file is only 147 MB

Firstly, why is WSS Search taking up so much space? How can I stop it from doing so, and what can I do now to get things running ok. I know about log file truncating and this isn't the case here since the log is tiny.

Any help is appreciated. There is plenty of free space on the disk (791GB free)

Thanks 
Kactus

Answer (score 0):

As per this snippet from this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298801.aspx#section1a) it sounds as if the search admin DB is allocated 10GB of space on creation.

> Search requires three databases. Your environment may include multiple Property and Crawl databases.
>
> The Search administration database is typically small: allocate 10 GB.
>
> To estimate the required storage for your Property and Crawl databases, use the following multipliers: 
>   Crawl: 0.046 × (sum of content databases)
>   Property: 0.015 × (sum of content databases)
>
> The IOPS requirements for Search are significant. 
>   For the Crawl database, search requires from 3,500 to 7,000 IOPS.
>
> For the Property database, search requires 2,000 IOPS.
>
> For detailed information about how to estimate capacity required for Search, see Performance and capacity test results and recommendations (SharePoint Server 2010).

Comment: Ouch - and it soundsl ike it should be on a SSD to ge those IOPS numbers. Discs are not even 10% of that requirement (7000).